# How do I print the field ID of a category field in place of its title?

Tags: templating

**How do I print the field ID of a category field in place of its title?**

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(category) %}
    some html...
    {% for category in entry.market.level(2).find() %}
        {{ category.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**I want to print the field ID of `category.title` instead.**

Reason = I am using the printed output as a class to filter against.  Some of the category titles contain more than one word and I do not want to add a hyphen to each instance.   So, using the field ID in place of category.title  would solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would using `{{ category.id }}` work?

Comment: That works.  I made the mistake of trying {{ category.fieldId }}.